# Dismiss Tooltip when hovering to next compontent

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I'm trying to configure tooltips via the `ToolTipManager`. My aim is to show tooltips after 2 secs and dismiss them after 5 secs. I achieved this with the below shown code snippet. This works perfect.

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay( 2000 );
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay( 5000);
```

Now I want to have this 2 secs delay also when I hover from one component to another compontent.
Example: I'm hovering menu item #1 and tooltip is shown. I hover to menu item #2 (while tooltip of menu item #1 is still shown) and the tooltip should dismiss and appear after 2 secs (initial delay).

I've tried [`setReshowDelay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#setReshowDelay-int-), but that didn't work in the way I expected.

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setReshowDelay( 0 );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* I suggest don't mess with either the initial delay ****or*** with dismissing the first tool tip when the user focuses another component. Mess with 'the path of least surprise' at your (and more importantly the user's) peril.

Comment: That's what the user wants. Even if it's weird.

Comment: use JLabel or JWindow instead of